# Disk space is lock or not release after moving files

Tags: samba, storage

I have this scenario, a disk is mount on and serves as storage device. shared to windows via samba. storage size is about 300GB and already full. i have tried to move files to another storage but still the free space dont change. Please help me.

Comment: **Edit** the post and add some _pictures_ will help.

Answer (score 0):

when ever i faced this type of problems..,
1.I tried to repair the disk using tools option.
2.Location of tools option is --> Right click on the disk 
                              --> Go to properities-->tools
                              --> click on error checking
                              --> Schedule disk check 
3.Finally restart your computer.

I hope this would help you

Comment: My apology, my storage device is mounted on a linux box with no gui. shared folder is acces in windows environment. sharing service is via samba. Will i try to repair the disk on windows or in linux? Thanks in advance. :D